# Send data from Adapter to Fragment and get it in fragment

Tags: android-fragments, nullpointerexception, adapter, android-recyclerview

in adapter

holder.nameexam2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("dataList.get(position).getId()",dataList.get(position).getId());
            Videos_botttomnav video= new Videos_botttomnav();
            video.setArguments(bundle);


        }
    }
```

in fragment

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

```
        String str =getArguments().getString("dataList.get(position).getId()");


        return view;
}
```

It invokes null pointer exception in getString(). how to resolve it.`enter code here`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I resolved the problem by adding childclicklistener in Recyclerview instead of sending data from adapter to fragment.